# Vim doesn't pick newly created color schemes

Tags: vim

I recently switched from Emacs to Vim so I'm kind of a newbie.
I found a bunch of colorschemes [here](http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com) and figured I would give [this](http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/colors/mod_tcsoft.vim) a shot.
I put it in my `/usr/share/vim/vim72/colors` directory.
Then I reopened my Vim and did:

```
:colorscheme mod_tcsoft
```

but it doesn't recognize my colorscheme.

(NOTE: when I copy paste directly from the site to my new `mod_tcsoft.vim` file it comments everything, so I omitted the comment section at the top. So that's not the problem. :) )

Do I have to do anything extra for Vim to pick it up?

Also how can I see list of available colorschemes in Vundle?

Comment: No, you *shouldn't have* to do anything for Vim to pick it up. Can you open the file from within vim and see whether it is of proper extension and content. Try sourcing it manually with :so % to check whether it works okey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work assuming that Vim is set up with that directory on the `runtimepath`, without needing to close and reopen Vim. Type `:set runtimepath?` - note the question mark at the end - and verify that `/usr/share/vim/vim72` is among the directories that are printed.

When you run `:colorscheme mod_tcsoft`, do you get an error: `Cannot find color scheme`?

Try instead to add the file to ~/.vim/colors. Create the intermediate directories if they don't exist: `mkdir -p ~/.vim/colors`.

> NOTE: when I copy paste directly from the site to my new `mod_tcsoft.vim` file it comments everything, so I omitted the comment section at the top. So that's not the problem.

Sounds like a `paste` issue. Are you running Vim in the terminal? If you paste and see problems like this, try `:set nopaste` before pasting, paste, and then `:set paste`.

Comment: thanks a lot! I had syntax error. thanks for all the info too

Comment: One more problem. So that color scheme said it loads, but only one of the colors on my code changes. I've tried to load a lot of different colorschemes and none of them load all the way. But I tried it in Macvim and macvim has the colors right. Any ideas why that would happen? would it have anything to do with mac's terminal?

Comment: actually I found the answer to my own questioN :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653538/how-can-i-activate-vim-color-schemes-in-os-xs-terminal