# vim doesn't show colors

Tags: macos, vim

I'm using Mac OS 10.8.2 terminal with option xterm256-color set

And when open files on local machine by vim it works fine. But when I go to server and open files there it doesn't work. All texts are white.

I check out the .vimrc on the server and syntax is also set (syntax on)

What can be a problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653538/how-can-i-activate-vim-color-schemes-in-os-xs-terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vim on your server using his own .vimrc.

**UPD**: an actual solution - [here](http://grasmash.com/article/osx-lion-terminal-unknown-terminal-xterm-256color).

Comment: What result you get if you type 'tput colors' on server session?

Comment: tput: unknown terminal "xterm-256color"  - if you mean that I should run this in bash

Comment: I found this article: http://grasmash.com/article/osx-lion-terminal-unknown-terminal-xterm-256color :)

Comment: This link doesn't work...